# Typescript change property type recursively

Tags: typescript

How to change property type recursively, im only able to do it in single dimension, judging from [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) it seem to possible to achive that, i have tried coupe of times but can't get it right

```
type Convert<V, O extends object> = {
    [Key in keyof O] : V
}

// single
{
    let original = {
        data1 : 1,
        data2 : 1,

    };

    let converted : Convert<string, typeof original> = {
        data1: 'a',
        data2: 'a',
    };
}

// recursive
{
    let original = {
        data1 : 1,
        data2 : 1,
        data3 : {
            data1 : 1,
            data2 : 1,
        }
    };

    let converted : Convert<string, typeof original> = {
        data1: 'a',
        data2: 'a',
        data3 : {
            data1 : 'a',
            data2 : 'a',
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want a recursive [conditional](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) type where you only recurse down into properties which are themselves objects:

```
type Convert<V, O extends object> = {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends object ? Convert<V, O[K]> : V
}
```

This will cause your example code to succeed, but there may be edge cases surrounding non-primitive properties you don't want to recurse into (e.g., arrays?), so you should test it thoroughly.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7ADwDUA0UDyUEAHsBAgCYDOUcARgFYQDGwAfFALxQDeAsACgowqAG0A0lACWCKAGsIIOADMCAXQBcBCWqKly1WoxbAoAfliIU6bHnw6OWrIIC+gwQHoPUKjIDmADYQgvxCIkGmcKhSfjIAhgFcvIIiqVAUccBxAIxa2TgpacIZWQBMeQUChcIuANzuYcIRUMxWaGQUWvDI7RhUwNEIfnigkCq00bEICRzcoUXFmTlaAORxK3jVaSVx5VBrG1t1rg1eUKgsAK6ovighW81RMfGJc1upO7lQ+e8iO3s-RrbJYAZi08wWHyWX0BkKhZQqvxqR3qVSBzVaPXQEE6lixmH6g2GUFGEHGTymMySEKKn1W60qkP+9MOQPhcTByTZCzp+wZSOBCL5rMhbiBxwELiAA)