# How do I recursively change property types from one to the other in an object with optional properties?

Tags: typescript

The situation:
I am using MongoDB with a REST API through JSON. MongoDB uses objects in place of identifiers for documents, but when stringified (eg sent as a response body) they are converted to strings.

The example below is obviously truncated a lot, but can be used to reproduce my question.

```
// Should recursively convert all ObjectId types to string types
type JsonDocument<D> = {
    [K in keyof D]: D[K] extends ObjectId ? string : D[K] extends object ? JsonDocument<D[K]> : D[K];
};

// The types for the document as it appears in the database
type FooDocument = {
    _id: ObjectId;
    updatedBy?: ObjectId;
};

// The types for the document as it appears in a response body
type FooJsonDocument = JsonDocument<FooDocument>;

// What I wanted FooJsonDocument to be
type ExpectedResult = {
    _id: string;
    updatedBy?: string;
};

// What FooJsonDocument actually is
type ActualResult = {
    _id: string;
    updatedBy?: ObjectId;
};
```

All required properties of type `ObjectId` are changed to `string` as expected, but not a single optional property of type `ObjectId` is changed.

How would I modify `JsonDocument` to also modify optional properties correctly?

> I came from [Typescript change property type recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255033/typescript-change-property-type-recursively), but this question does not ask about optional properties, so I feel like it's not a duplicate. Still, it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `(ObjectID | undefined) extends ObjectID` is not true, because `undefined extends ObjectID` is not true. So it takes the negative branch of the conditional.

Since you don't care that the values are optional, you can remove `undefined` from the type before you test it. That way `ObjectID extends ObjectID` is true, and you take the positive conditional path.

You can do that with by either making all properties required `Required<D>` or removing nullability from each property as you test it `NonNullable<D[K]>`.

```
type JsonDocument<D> = {
    [K in keyof D]:
        NonNullable<D[K]> extends ObjectId ? string
        : D[K] extends object ? JsonDocument<D[K]>
        : D[K];
};
```

[Working example on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgJIAmyA3ssACID24A0iJQO4DqAFnGBtrngM4BCAV3xgAyi0oCANgXABZdpCgAuZDzBRQAc2QBfAFB6A9IeRiJ05FBwCoPYADcIkgJ7IE1R1DDI4kyWiwcfCIwZwAHCB5kMEpVdS1o8Mi9UIjkACkeaioEAQBbCHAAHnIAPmQAXhI9ZFrkAG0aMhBkAGsIZ0oYZHIAXSUauqGAOWphqUk4dEkIEsbe8ogAD0gQAijOIMJkAH44jRBNQaHalXJ55GXV9eRKQNxdjKyQHPzCsDmaBeOTs-mAbj0OkBRhMABUWChUpFkDBKFBopDkARKLkCuAfFFgN44GEInBbM1ESgCOwpnAeBAUklkAAxSiUV7o7xVYg-AD6wAIKk23AIgKGAjCpMgBD4zh2PPuwUBwIM0OQAEFKsgAEoQACOAmAVgIRXpjNRb3ApWpaT4Ksy2SNzKKitNoOQEKhSSicIRYCRKLR70xZBxeIgBKxLTglkiYWolOQ6EoBGcZpQBqtLxtvqqKaZ731DKzJsBhgAVIm6QzM2mMayOVyVGoDpoBXUhSKIGKJbX4odkAAfZACNYQGCgVuyvSFwxAA)

Answer (score 0):

This is the type I use for JSON:

```
type Unserializable = Function | RegExp | Error;

export type ToJSON<T> = T extends undefined
    ? ToJSON<T extends undefined ? never : T> | undefined
    : T extends Unserializable
    ? never
    : T extends { toJSON: () => any }
    ? ReturnType<T['toJSON']>
    : T extends object
    ? {
            [K in keyof T]: ToJSON<T[K]>;
      }
    : T extends (infer A)[]
    ? ToJSON<A>[]
    : T;
```

The `JSON.stringify` function is using the `toJSON` method when finding one, so it works for any JSON serializable type (including ObjectId, Date).

It also handles optional properties (inspiration was found in `NonUndefined` from [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types))